Add ink to OneNote pages via Microsoft Graph API
I am trying to add ink to OneNote pages through the Microsoft Graph API. I have read this article, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/onenote-ink-beta-apis/, but it was written in 2017 and it seems that the graph api is preferred now.
I tried using this curl command:
    curl -X POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/[id]/pages \
         -H "Authorization: Bearer [...]" \
         -H "Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml" \
         -H "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=presentation-onenote-inkml" \
         --data-binary @- <<EOF
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <inkml:ink xmlns:emma="http://www.w3.org/2003/04/emma"     xmlns:msink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ink/2010/main"     xmlns:inkml="http://www.w3.org/2003/InkML">
     <inkml:definitions>
      <inkml:context xml:id="ctxCoordinatesWithPressure">
       <inkml:inkSource xml:id="inkSrcCoordinatesWithPressure">
        <inkml:traceFormat>
         <inkml:channel name="X" type="integer" max="32767" units="himetric"/>
         <inkml:channel name="Y" type="integer" max="32767" units="himetric"/>
         <inkml:channel name="F" type="integer" max="32767" units="dev"/>
        </inkml:traceFormat>
        <inkml:channelProperties>
         <inkml:channelProperty channel="X" name="resolution" value="1" units="1/himetric"/>
         <inkml:channelProperty channel="Y" name="resolution" value="1" units="1/himetric"/>
         <inkml:channelProperty channel="F" name="resolution" value="1" units="1/dev"/>
        </inkml:channelProperties>
       </inkml:inkSource>
      </inkml:context>
      <inkml:brush xml:id="br0">
       <inkml:brushProperty name="width" value="100" units="himetric"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="height" value="100" units="himetric"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="color" value="#0000FF"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="transparency" value="0"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="tip" value="ellipse"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="rasterOp" value="copyPen"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="ignorePressure" value="false"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="antiAliased" value="true"/>
       <inkml:brushProperty name="fitToCurve" value="false"/>
      </inkml:brush>
     </inkml:definitions>
     <inkml:traceGroup>
      <inkml:trace xml:id="st1" contextRef="#ctxCoordinatesWithPressure" brushRef="#br0">12105     14014 2560, 11649 14071 3840, 11047 14166 5120, 10839 14195 4992, 10549 14222 5504, 10237 14227 6144, 9909 14199 7040, 9622 14125 7936, 9375 13991 8704, 9181 13790 9472, 9045 13516 9856, 8977 13152 10368, 8986 12709 10368, 9088 12189 10368, 9250 11614 10240, 9475 11031 10240, 9742 10459 10112, 10020 9923 10112, 10277 9438 9984, 10492 9022 9856, 10655 8667 9856, 10748 8376 9856, 10777 8140 9856, 10751 7959 9856, 10656 7819 9856, 10504 7726 9984, 10285 7668 10112, 10018 7668 10240, 9680 7720 10240, 9293 7824 10240, 8898 7982 10240, 8491 8177 10368, 8115 8387 10112, 7794 8584 9984, 7547 8740 9472, 7387 8839 8960, 7334 8875 7808, 7362 8846 6784, 7504 8715 3456, 7800 8473 256</inkml:trace>
     </inkml:traceGroup>
    </inkml:ink>
    EOF


but what gets written to the page is just the numbers in the <inkml: trace></inkml: trace>
I also tried the http request in the https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/onenote-ink-beta-apis/ but replaced the url with the graph note url, but I keep getting the error The multi-part payload was malformed.". I see a lot of people talk about how the use inkML in-conjunction with the oneNote API based on that blog post, but I am just confused as to how they achieved it.
I figured out how to get inkML from oneNote, but I don't now to write ink to oneNote via API.
If anyone can show me how to do this, I will be ever so grateful.
Thanks to anyone that responds :)

Are you able to get the example to work in graph explorer. If that works at least you know your payload is correct. This API is really nitpicky and the only response you get is very generic. I was caught out by not using the  for new lines as I run things on a Mac
